# Rails looping through params data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am parsing an excel file and passing the data to my controller but I cannot seem to loop through it in my view:

**Params:**

```
Parameters: {"data"=>{"consult_charges"=>[{"id"=>"17474", "item"=>"Consultation", "name"=>"Ramon", "price"=>"25.0"}, {"id"=>"17584", "item"=>"Consultation", "name"=>"Ramon", "price"=>"25.0"}, {"id"=>"17490", "item"=>"Consultation", "name"=>"Elizabeth", "price"=>"25.0"}, {"id"=>"17515", "item"=>"Consultation", "name"=>"Elizabeth", "price"=>"25.0"}, {"id"=>"17554", "item"=>"Consultation", "name"=>" Elizabeth", "price"=>"25.0"}, {"id"=>"17623", "item"=>"Consult - Referral Card", "name"=>"Elizabeth", "price"=>"0.0"}, {"id"=>"17486", "item"=>"Consultation", "name"=>"Racha", "price"=>"25.0"}
```

**Controller:**

```
@consult_charges = params["data"]["consult_charges"]
```

**View:**

```
<table class="table awaken">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @consult_charges.each do |sale| %>
            <td><%= sale["id"] %></td>
            <td><%= sale["name"] %></td>
            <td><%= sale["item"] %></td>
            <td><%= sale["price"] %></td>
        <% end -%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result is a single line of data as if there is only one `sale`.  When I look at the value for `@consult_charges` it's an array of items like this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"17584", "item"=>"Consultation", "name"=>"Ramon", "price"=>"25.0"} permitted: false>
```

Do I need to do something to convert the type?

Comment: aren't you forgetting to put `<tr>` for each iteration?

Comment: oh god... this is embarassing

Comment: have you tried `to_a` to convert it?

Comment: @JeremyThomas happens to all of us :D. Added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's showing just one line is because `<tr>` tag is missing on each iteration. Change your view to;

```
<table class="table awaken">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @consult_charges.each do |sale| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= sale["id"] %></td>
            <td><%= sale["name"] %></td>
            <td><%= sale["item"] %></td>
            <td><%= sale["price"] %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end -%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```